# pandas Series: find column by value

Tags: pandas, series

I have a pandas series and a value. I want to find which column contains my value and get the columns name. The value is guaranteed to appear exactly once.

```
Column A| Column B | Column C
   rtz       xyz          abc
```

And my value is `abc` I want `Column C` as return value.

How can I do that?

EDIT:

I have a series so anything using df.columns etc. will not work as series has no columns attribute.

Comment: Series not DataFrame

Comment: Answer was edited for `Series`

Comment: using @jezrael data : ``s.index[s.eq("abc")]``

Comment: @sammywemmy - array is not important, should be removed ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for positions of matched values, indexing and then use `next` with `iter` trick for return first matched value, it working also if no match:

```
i, c = np.where(df == 'abc')
print (c)
[2]

print (next(iter(df.columns[c]), 'no match'))
Column C
```

---

```
i, c = np.where(df == 'abc1')
print (c)
[]

print (next(iter(df.columns[c]), 'no match'))
no match
```

EDIT: Solution with `Series`:

```
s = pd.Series(['rtz','xyz','abc'], index=list('ABC'))
    
print (next(iter(s[s == 'abc'].index), 'no match'))
C

print (next(iter(s[s == 'abc1'].index), 'no match'))
no match
```

Alternative:

```
print (next(iter(s.index[s == 'abc']), 'no match'))
C

print (next(iter(s.index[s == 'abc1']), 'no match'))
no match
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try select string value. Using the `.iloc` accessor extract the column array/list and call the element in list using `[index]`

```
(df.columns[(df=='abc').iloc[0]])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

So while waiting for answers I came up with my own seemingly naive answer:

```
for col_name, value in s.items():
    if value == 'abc':
        //do stuff
        break
```

Simply iterating the series in a for loop. Yeah I'm a bit old-school not yet much accustomed to functional programming paradigms. therefore I also tend to ask for potentially better solutions.

I then had a feeling after applying jezraels solution that my script got slower. (the specific code is called a lot) I expected a speed up over simple looping but turns out I was very wrong:

```
s = pd.Series(['rtz','abc','xyz'], index=list('ABC'))  

%%timeit
next(iter(s[s == 'abc'].index), 'no match')
224 µs ± 3.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit
for col_name, value in s.items():
    if value == 'abc':
        col_name
        break
15.9 µs ± 159 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Simple for loop is over 10x times faster for this specific use-case (small series, eg around 20 items in my use-case). That is pretty puzzling actually. So if performance matters and you have a tiny series I guess this is the way to go.

Comment: It depends of data. If use `s = pd.Series(['rtz','xyz'] * 10000 + ['abc'])` then I got `In [211]: %%timeit
     ...: for col_name, value in s.items():
     ...:     if value == 'abc':
     ...:         col_name
     ...:         break
     ...:         
5.04 ms ± 92.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [212]: %%timeit
     ...: next(iter(s[s == 'abc'].index), 'no match')
     ...: 
1.31 ms ± 24.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
`

Comment: I test worse scenariou when matched value is last value of `Series`

Comment: Interesting. for me with this larger example the looping is still a bit faster (1.5 vs 1.1 ms). anyway hence my disclaimer of a small series.